# Rebase branch with 1 file added on shallow clone?

Tags: git, homebrew, git-rebase, shallow-clone

I've forked Homebrew, branched to add a formula, and pushed to my fork.

Now I'm on a new machine, my fork is several (tens, hundreds, thousands of) commits behind.

The local Homebrew repo is thus a shallow clone, where my branch occurs in the distant and not-held past.

How can I fetch my fork into a local branch rebased onto master?

Anticipating "you can't with missing history", I would say - there's surely a way, when the patch is so simple as a few commits that add a single subsequently modified file?

Comment: what issue do you have fetching your fixed branch from the fork? I believe it should be possible. You probably won't be able to merge then, because it won't find merge base, but rebase should be possible also

Answer (score 0):

You could export your branch as a series of patches from a repo where the branch is present:

```
git format-patch `git merge-base formula master`..formula
```

Copy those patches to your fork, and apply them with [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) in a new branch on top of `master`

See "[Patching with "`git format-patch`" and "`git am`"](http://cloudspace.com/blog/2010/07/14/patching-with-git-format-patch-and-git-am/#.VoTtAlm-OT8)" as an example.

But the key point, of course, if that you have to have access first to a repo which includes your `formula` commits (to export them).

Comment: So if I was on a new install for example, I would clone both the newer history - viz. install homebrew - and, to a separate folder, the out of date repo with my branch, from which I could export?

Comment: @oll yes, that is the idea: you need to access the older repo with your branch in it in order to export it.